# SQL Server 2014 : how to get records that have rows of different values of only particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, having

Our customers have accounts with us for their vehicles. Some customers have multiple vehicles, hence multiple licence plates. Sometimes, some customers have different Insurance Accounts for their vehicles too.

I need a list of accounts that have:

1. More than 1 licence plate and
2. More than 1 insurance account ID

I'm using 3 tables:

- `Account` table A for account info
- `Plate` table P for licence plate info
- `EventLog` table E for info when notice letter was sent

Relationship:

```
A.AccountId = P.AccountId = E.AccountId
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT 
    A.AccountNumber, A.AccountId, A.CurrentBalance,
    E.NotificationDt,
    P.LicPlateNo, A.RegistrationTypeId, P.InsuranceAccountId
FROM 
    Account A
INNER JOIN 
    Plate P ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId
INNER JOIN  
    EventLog E ON A.AccountId = E.AccountId
WHERE 
    A.RegistrationTypeId = 3
    AND P.EndDate IS NULL               
    AND A.AccountStatusId = 1           
    AND A.DelinquencyStatusId = 11
    AND E.EventId = 64
    AND P.PlateStatusId = 1
ORDER BY 
    AccountNumber, A.AccountId, P.LicPlateNo
```

My sample data looks like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---+--------+
|AccNo    | AccId   |CurrBal  |NotifDt      |LicPlateNo|RTI|InsAccId|
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---+--------+
|21234561 |123456   |    56.79|   2017-01-01|ABC123    |  3|1234ABC |
|21234572 |123457   |    83.25|   2017-01-03|DEF345    |  3|345DEF  |
|22345672 |234567   |   104.38|   2017-01-03|GHI345    |  3|567GHI  |
|22345672 |234568   |   104.38|   2017-01-03|JKL678    |  3|789MNO  |
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---+--------+
```

In my sample data, the last two columns are for the same `AccountNumber` which has different `LicencePlateNos` and different `Insurance AccountIds`.

I would like my data to look like this:

```
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---+--------+
|22345672 |234567   |   104.38|   2017-01-03|GHI345    |  3|567GHI  |
|22345672 |234568   |   104.38|   2017-01-03|JKL678    |  3|789MNO  |
+---------+---------+---------+-------------+----------+---+--------+
```

What would the code be that would give me that data?

I tried using a `GROUP BY... HAVING` clause but that gives me only the unique `AccountNumber`s that have multiple licence plates. I would like to show the different licence plate nos and the different `InsuranceAccountID`s as well.

Comment: Can you add column headers to your sample data?  I assume it should match your sample query but might be good to specify.

Comment: Added abbreviated headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to JOIN a result set that would allow you for checking for either or both conditions.  Just include the appropriate filter clause:

```
...
INNER JOIN EventLog E ON A.AccountId = E.AccountId

INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        Plate.AccountId,
        LicensePlateCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Plate.LicPlateNo),
        InsuranceAccountCount = COUNT(DISTINCT Plate.InsuranceAccountId)
    FROM
        Plate
    WHERE
        Plate.EndDate IS NULL
        AND Plate.PlateStatusId = 1
    GROUP BY
        Plate.AccountId
) PlateAccounts ON A.AccountId = PlateAccounts.AccountId
    -- 1) More than 1 License Plate:
    AND PlateAccounts.LicensePlateCount > 1
    -- 2) More than 1 Insurance Account IDs:
    AND PlateAccounts.InsuranceAccountCount > 1

WHERE A.RegistrationTypeId = 3
...
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you, Doug. But what code would I have ABOVE the INNER JOIN ?

Comment: @user1777929 - I added a line of code above and below so you can see where to insert this code.

Comment: Thank you Doug. Worked great. However, while I get different rows with multiple Licence Plates, I get multiple rows with the same Insurance Account Nos. ____  The goal really was to get unique, different Insurance Account numbers for each account that had them.... because ideally, each account should have only ONE Insurance Account Number...... Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user1777929 - Can you give an example result you are seeing that isn't what you are looking for?  If you only want the Accounts with multiple Insurance Account Numbers, try commenting out the line "AND PlateAccounts.LicensePlateCount > 1".

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use your query as a base and count the values with more than one row:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT A.AccountNumber, A.AccountId, A.CurrentBalance, E.NotificationDt,
             P.LicPlateNo, A.RegistrationTypeId, P.InsuranceAccountId,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.AccountNumber) as cnt
      FROM Account A INNER JOIN
           Plate P
           ON A.AccountId = P.AccountId INNER JOIN
           EventLog E
           ON A.AccountId = E.AccountId
      WHERE A.RegistrationTypeId = 3 AND
            P.EndDate IS NULL AND  
            A.AccountStatusId = 1 AND        
            A.DelinquencyStatusId = 11 AND
            E.EventId = 64 AND
            P.PlateStatusId = 1
     ) a
WHERE cnt > 1;   
ORDER BY AccountNumber, AccountId, LicPlateNo;
```

Comment: This code is nice but I get duplicate Insurance Account Numbers. I need Account numbers with distinct separate Licence Plates and Distinct separate Insurance Account Numbers. Thanks for your help.